# Python arrays for objects

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I would like to make a numpy-like multi-dimensional array of non-numerical objects in python. I believe Numpy arrays only allow numerical values. List-of-lists are much less convenient to index- for example, I'd like to be able to ask for myarray[1,:,2] which requires much more complicated calls from lists of lists.

Is there a good tool for this?

Answer (score 1):

NumPy arrays actually do allow non-numerical contents, so you can just use NumPy.

Comment: I can't figure out how. When I try np.full((2,2), foo()) where foo is a class, I get [[0.,0.],[0.,0.]]. When I check the type of the entries they are 'numpy.float64'. What am I missing?

Comment: try: np.array([[foo(), foo()], [foo(), foo()]])

Comment: @ericksonla: First, [`np.full` defaults to a dtype of float](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full), so you should specify `dtype=object` instead. Second, you're making *one* `foo()` object for all cells of the entire array. If that's not what you want, something like `np.vectorize(lambda arg: foo())(np.empty([2, 2]))` might be more appropriate.